# Long math in Java

Tags: java, date, math, long-integer

I am having a little trouble with some long math in java.
What I am trying to do is display a date in weeks so i can calculate the time from two weeks. I have looked at a few tutorials but none seem to have worked.

here is the code for the problem

```
public void onClick(View v) 
 { //for the placement date
     final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
     showDialog(START_DATE_DIALOG_ID);


     placementDate = new Long(cal.getTimeInMillis());
     placementDate /=604800000L; //takes the date in ms to weeks
 }
```

I am doing this function twice with two dates so when outputting in just ms format I am getting two different numbers:

- 11/April/2014 - 1397217773259
- 12/May/2014  - 1397217815087

When dividing I end up getting the exact same value for both being 2310

I have tried two formats currently to work out the days 1st being the way showed in the code dividing the date by 86400000 and the second dividing by (1000* 60*60*24 *7) each way  results in the output of 2310. I just dont understand or seem to be able to find  way to make it work the way it should

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Long math. Indeed the correct answer to both is 2310. The difference is only 0.000069, which gets rounded down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy Math
Year = 52 weeks roughly cause it is something like 52.12
52*current year + courent year week
Thats it!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     double year =cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     double month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     double weekOfYear = Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
     double currentYearWeeks = (year-1)*52 + weekOfYear;
     double weekAgo = (year-1)*52 + weekOfYear -1;
     double monthAgo = (year-1)*52 + weekOfYear - 4;
     System.out.println("Difference:" + (currentYearWeeks - weekAgo));
     System.out.println("Difference:" + (currentYearWeeks - weekAgo));
     System.out.println("Difference:" + (currentYearWeeks - monthAgo));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the numbers you have shown, 1397217773259 and 1397217815087, is 41828 or less than 42 *seconds*. This is clearly much less than your divisor, 604800000.

Check your `Calendar` logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the week number use this :

```
cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```